# settextformat function in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am trying to apply setTextFormat function for my dynamic text filed in as 3,

but its not taking. Please have a look at my code and suggest me where i am going wrong.

```
var name1:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(name1);

var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.color = 0x000000;
format.size = 18;
format.underline = true;
format.italic = true;

function imagerollover(e:MouseEvent):void{    
     name1.setTextFormat(format);
     name1.visible = true;
     name1.text = myXML.data[Number(e.currentTarget.name)].@description;            
}
```

Am taking images and description from an external xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name1.visible = true;
name1.text = myXML.data[Number(e.currentTarget.name)].@description; 
name1.setTextFormat(format);
```

change your seaquence of coding like this.

Comment: Yes its is working!. Thank you. But how to do it the text should be displayed on mouse over?

Comment: actually your coding is right... 

defaultTextFormat should not work in mouseover.

I have edited my post.. see that.

Comment: No that is working properly. I have used something like this, 

`function imagerollover(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 
 //var mXML:XML;
 name1.defaultTextFormat=format;
 name1.setTextFormat(format);
  name1.visible = true;
name1.text = myXML.data[Number(e.currentTarget.name)].@description; 
 
 } `

Comment: But my problem is: as i have set x, y position it displays description there itself, but what i want is if mouse is over image 1, description should be displayed on image 1, if on image 2, description also on image 2.... like this

Comment: remove this "name1.defaultTextFormat=format; " and place this "name1.setTextFormat(format);" after assign the txt to the TextField.

Comment: And also i want to no, how to put multiline format within this?

Comment: assigning the txt to the Textfiled means? Sorry can you please explain me . i did not get...